# mat-tab-group scrolls to top of page when tab index changes

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have weird behaviour on `mat-tab-group` in Angular Material.

When I change tab index it scrolls the page to top.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is a known bug in the angular material library (see [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9592)) which has not been fixed yet.

The current workaround is to apply a `min-height` to the parent element of `mat-tab-group`

Answer (score 10):

You can avoid this by adding a min-height to your mat-tab-group.

Exemple :

```
<mat-tab-group style='min-height:300px'>
```

Answer (score 6):

The predefined minimum height will not work for dynamic heights (tabs where the size of the content changes), so the most responsive solution is to modify it when changing tabs so that the new tab stays with the minimum height of the previous one to avoid scroll up

---

//HTML

```
<mat-tab-group #matTabGroup (selectedTabChange)="onMatTabChanged();">
```

---

//TS

```
@ViewChild('matTabGroup', { static: true }) matTabGroup: MatTabGroup;

onMatTabChanged() {
  this.setMatTabGroup();
}

setMatTabGroup() {
  let ntvEl = this.matTabGroup._elementRef.nativeElement;
  ntvEl.style.minHeight = ntvEl.clientHeight + 'px';
}
```

Comment: This is nice but leaves a gap at the bottom of any tabs that are shorter after you switch.  I did `ntvEl.style.minHeight  = '0px';` before setting it to the clientHeight **and** used the `<mat-tab-group style='min-height:800px'>` trick from above (with a high enough number for your case).  It now seems to work in all scenarios as I'd expect.